# Serializing form in jquery and passing it into php

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying for the last couple of days to serialize a form in jquery and pass it to php.  For some reason it just doesn't work...  Question, What steps do you take to serialize a form in Jquery...  I get the id of the form pass it into $('#fomrID').serialize()...

And it still doesn't work.  When I debugg with firebug All I get is an empty string... Do you use the name or the Id of the form.  Do you use e.disableDefalut or whatever that is?  I can't figure out why I can't serialize my form please help

```
    $('#profilepicbutton').change(function(){
    alert("Boy I hate PHP");
    var formElement = $('#profilepicinput').attr('value');
    dataString = $("#registerpt3").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register3.php",
            data: dataString, //"profilePic="+formElement,
            success: function(data){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "retrievePic.php", 
                    data: "",                   
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        var image = new Image();
                        $(image).load(function(){
                            console.log("we have uploaded this image");
                        }).attr('src', 'images/');
                        alert("");                      
                    },
                    error: function(msg){
                        alert("");
                    }
                });
            },
            error:function(msq){
                alert("" + msg);
            }
        }
    );
});


    <form  id="registerpt3" name="registerpt3" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register3.php" onSubmit="" method="post">
<input name="profilepicinput" type="file" id="profilepicbutton"  />
</form>
```

Comment: You haven't declared dataString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/serialize

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. **Data from file select elements is not serialized.**

Also, simply calling serialize won't actually upload the picture for you.  If you want to do an asynchronous picture upload (or any file for that matter) I'd suggest looking into something like Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Well, that is all well and good, but why on earth doesn't my php script get the file at all?  I only want to use free utilities.  I am attempting to implement valumns solution (after finally finding it).  I can't understand why my php script simply doesn't work...

Comment: For two reasons, 1) serialize() doesn't actually grab data from file elements.  The second has to do with file uploads, do some googling about PHP file uploads and that'll teach you all you need to know.